# Design a caculator with Yacc and Lex that deals with mutiple types

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I'm new to Compiler building. There are many examples for the =-*/ operations out there we can find by Google, but the tokens in those examples in lex usually only deal with one type, for example `%token<DOUBLE> NUMBER`, and then the expression type in yacc will also be DOUBLE, for example `%type<DOUBLE> expr factor term`.

I included an example grammar for that:

```
lines
:
| lines expression '\n'  { printf(" = %lf\n", $2); }
;

expr
: term   { $$ = $1; }
| expr '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
| expr '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
;

term
: factor   { $$ = $1; }
| term '*' factor  { $$ = $1 * $3; }
| term '/' factor  { $$ = $1 / $3; }
;

factor
: NUMBER   { $$ = $1; }
| group   { $$ = $1; }
;

group
: '(' expression ')' { $$ = $2; }
;
```

If I want to deal with different types, for example FLOAT and INTEGER instead of DOUBLE, I would do that like this:

```
%type<INTEGER> Integer
%type<FLOAT>   Float
lines
:
| lines expression '\n'  { printf(" = %lf\n", $2); }
;

expr
: term   { $$ = $1; }
| expr '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }
| expr '-' term { $$ = $1 - $3; }
;

term
: factor   { $$ = $1; }
| term '*' factor  { $$ = $1 * $3; }
| term '/' factor  { $$ = $1 / $3; }
;

factor
: Integer   { $$ = $1; }
| Float   { $$ = $1;}
| group   { $$ = $1; }
;

group
: '(' expression ')' { $$ = $2; }
;
```

How to define the types of expressions like expr, factor, term, constant?

If I don't assign them a type there will be an error saying the expression is untyped, but if I assign them the type INTEGER there will also be an error since the factor can be reduced to INTEGER or FLOAT.

How to deal with that?

Comment: If you type `1+2`, what type the expression is? If you type `3.0*2.75`, what type the expression is? Do you want this handled by one `expression` production in your grammar or two (e.g. `expression_type_int` and `expression_type_float`)?

Comment: i want to know if there is any solution to handle it by one expression which can deal with something just like you say type 1+2 , and type 3.0*2.75  in my grammar .

Comment: OK so you want something that can handle both reals and integers and maybe something more, all in a single data type. You may want to use a *union*, or more precisely, a tagged union. You will have to deal with all possible combinations yourself, as builtin arithmetic operators won't work on unions. Write a function for each operator, say `MyNumberType add(MyNumberType n1, MyNumberType n2)` and analyze each combination inside. You will call e.g. `$$=add($1,$3)`.

Comment: so if we want to handle different type we have to design a function. Should we still define the type of the expression? thanks for the response !

Comment: The type of the expression is `MyNumberType`, you need to define it. You can do it by defining the YYSTYPE macro (the old yacc way) or by defining `%define api.value.type {MyNumberType}` (the new bison way). You can also use the %type declaration like you did, but you have to do it for **all** productions.

Comment: I recommend using the %left and %right directives to specify operator precedence and associativity rather than trying to do that through levels in the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Type inference (determining which type an expression is) isn't normally handled by the parser as such but is determined later in the semantic analysis phase, e.g. by having a getType() function that can accept any AST node and return its type.